# Lebesgue measure of transcendental numbers in $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers

What is the Lebesgue measure of the transcendental numbers in the $[0,1]$ interval? I was not able to find any information on this. (Does this question even make sense given what we currently know about transcendental numbers?)

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be one because $[0,1]=\{x\in [0,1]\mid \text{$x$ transcendental}\}\cup \{x\in [0,1]\mid \text{$x$ algebraic}\}$, and the last set is countable and thus has Lesbesgue measure zero.  Because these two sets are disjoint, we find that the measure must be 1

Comment: Oh whoops... I was not thinking. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algebraic numbers are countable (a basic exercise in every undergraduate real analysis text). Countable sets have measure zero, so the complement has full measure ($=1$).

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** The algebraic numbers are countable.